# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with smallint error in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

i have write a sql query to fetch employee hire count between 2006 to 2008 . here is my code from adventurework2014.dimemployee table

```
SELECT YEAR(cast('HireDate' as int)), DepartmentName,
        count(ParentEmployeeKey) AS 'total emplyee join' 
FROM DimEmployee 
where HireDate between 2006 and 2008 
group by DepartmentName, HireDate,FirstName,ParentEmployeeKey
ORDER BY  YEAR(HireDate)
```

my above code showing error

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with smallint

please help me with some solution .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below statement will take `HireDate` as string, which can't be converted to int.

```
cast('HireDate' as int)
```

Ideally you don't need to convert it into int, if you use `YEAR` on date, it will give you int only.

Change your query like following.

```
SELECT YEAR(HireDate), DepartmentName,
            count(ParentEmployeeKey) AS 'total emplyee join' 
    FROM DimEmployee 
    where YEAR(HireDate) >= 2006 and YEAR(HireDate) <= 2008 
    group by DepartmentName, HireDate,FirstName,ParentEmployeeKey
    ORDER BY  YEAR(HireDate)
```

Comment: perfect now . i have learn very important thing about year function and cast function . thanks

Answer (score 4):

You missed to use `year()` in `where` clause :

```
where year(HireDate) >= 2006 and year(HireDate) <= 2008
```

Further more you also don't need to use `cast()` function with `year()` as it will return numeric type.

Your `SELECT` statement is strange for me it should have aggregated column when you include `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT YEAR(HireDate), DepartmentName,
       count(ParentEmployeeKey) AS 'total emplyee join' 
FROM DimEmployee 
WHERE year(HireDate) >= 2006 and year(HireDate) <= 2008 
GROUP BY DepartmentName, YEAR(HireDate), FirstName, ParentEmployeeKey
ORDER BY YEAR(HireDate);
```

Comment: I think it should also avoid the cast to int of hiredate

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below,

```
SELECT YEAR(cast(HireDate as date)), DepartmentName,
        count(ParentEmployeeKey) AS 'total emplyee join' 
FROM DimEmployee 
where YEAR(cast(HireDate as date)) between 2006 and 2008 
group by DepartmentName, HireDate,FirstName,ParentEmployeeKey
ORDER BY  YEAR(cast(HireDate as date))
```

If your column 'HireDate' is datetime field , you don't need any cast